# My python program exits instead of looping

Tags: python, pyautogui

I've been working with Python on and off for the last year and found a 'spam program' on YouTube which I then tried to rewrite so that it will repeat for a defined amount. But even if I enter a five the program will still only write one time and then exit. And I don't know what I did wrong.

```
import pyautogui
import time

f = open("E:\Documents\Coding-Projekte\Python\Spammer\spamtext", 'r')

count = int(input("How often to write the text: "))

time.sleep(5)


def spam():
    print("Start Spam")
    if count > 0:
        for word in f:
            if ":" in word:
                pyautogui.typewrite(word)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
                time.sleep(0.5)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
                count - 1
                print("wrote line")
                spam()
            else:
                pyautogui.typewrite(word)
                pyautogui.press("enter")
                count - 1
                print("wrote line")
                spam()
    else:
        exit()


spam()
```

Comment: Why are you calling `spam()` inside `spam()`? Have you misunderstood how loops work?

Comment: `if count > 0:` isn't a loop, so it won't loop.

Comment: Why are you using recursion instead of a simple `while` loop? `count - 1` also doesn't *change* the value of `count`.

Comment: Also, since you only open the file once, eventually you'll reach the end of the file, and since you never re-open or reset the file counter, `for word in f:` will simply not be entered. That would explain the file only being written once, but since `count > 0` will never be false, the only way your program will exit is via an uncaught `RecursionError`.

Comment: @chepner My mistake was to not reopen the file so I moved that into the loop and changed it to while. Also I changed `count-1` to `count -= 1` so that it would really subtract instead of just doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if count > 0:` with `for repetition in range(count):`.